# Check for consecutive numbers

Tags: arrays, ruby, integer, conditional-statements

I have an array `m` of integers. I'm looking for a method to check if the elements of `m` are consecutive. Is there a way to test for consecutive numbers?

I came up with this code intended to work when the array length is four:

```
m.count == 4 && (m.max-m.min) == 3
```

which incorrectly returns `true` for `[1,1,1,4]` or `[0,0,0,3]`.

Comment: do you want `[4,6,5,7]` to pass?

Comment: Simplest possible?: `m.count==4 && (m.size-1).times.all? { |i| m[i+1] == m[i] + 1 }`.

Comment: @illusionist, see [this Wiki](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consecutive_integer) for a definition of consecutive integers. So `[4,6,5,7]` should return `false`.

Comment: `[4, 3, 2, 1]` is consecutive. Do you want it to pass only when the series is increasing?

Comment: @sawa, the Wiki link I gave, though not authoritative, defines sequences of consecutive integers to be increasing only.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I am not clear whether "follow each other **in order**" means increasing. Do you mean that part? I cannot find any other part that might be mentioning increasing.

Comment: Another way: `def test(a,n); return false unless a.size == n; enum = a.to_enum; loop do; return false unless enum.next == enum.peek-1; end; true; end`.

Comment: @sawa, I don't know, but all the examples have increasing sequences. I defer to Mrs. Mullet, my 3rd grade teacher, who defined consecutive numbers by example: `1,2,3,4...` (and who was not contradicted by any of my later teachers, through graduate school), but there are plenty of internet authorities who claim that `2,4,6` and `6,4,2` are sequences of consecutive numbers. We can agree, however, that `3,5,4,6` is not a sequence of consecutive integers.

Comment: @sawa, those examples do not contradict. "Consecutive real numbers" is simply not defined. It's interesting that there are many, many theorems concerning "consecutive integers" that are only correct if the `1,2,3,..` definition applies, yet the term "consecutive" is usually not defined. All that's important here, however, is what the OP wants.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Sorry. I mistook "continuous" with "consecutive" in my last comment.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Enumerable has a really handy method called [`each_cons`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_cons) that works like this:

```
[1,2,3,4].each_cons(2).to_a # => [ [1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4] ]
```

That is, it yields each consecutive set of *n* elements. In our case *n* is 2.

Of course, as the name implies, it returns an Enumerator, so we can chain it with other Enumerable methods like `all?`:

```
def four_consecutive?(arr)
  return false unless arr.size == 4
  arr.each_cons(2).all? {|a, b| b == a + 1 }
end

four_consecutive?([2,3,4,5])   # => true
four_consecutive?([2,2,2,5])   # => false
four_consecutive?([1,2,3,4,5]) # => false
```

This method has the advantage above others that, because `all?` short-circuits as soon as the block returns false, it will only test numbers until it finds a pair that don't meet the condition (`b == a + 1`). Of course, with only four elements this doesn't really make a difference—unless you're calling this method thousands of times in situation where performance matters.

Answer (score 6):

You can try this:

```
a == (a.min..a.max).to_a && a.count == 4
```

This only works when the array is in increasing order. `[3, 4, 5, 6]` will pass but `[4, 3, 5, 6]` won't.

Comment: I think this does not pass ` [4, 3, 5, 6] `

Comment: @illusionist, that returns false, as it should. There is a problem, however, as `a = [1,2,3]` returns `true` even though `a` does not contain `4` elements.

Comment: @CarySwoveland edited to take `a.count` into considaration

Answer (score 4):

The Answer is based on mathematical problem for `Sum of consecutive integers`

```
Sum = n∗(n+1)/2
```

Code:

```
def check_sum_match?(arr)
  m = arr.min - 1
  n = arr.max
  sum1 = arr.inject{|sum, x| sum = sum + x}
  sum2 = (n*(n+1) - m*(m+1))/2
  sum1 == sum2
end

arr = [5,6,7,8]
if arr.count == 4 && check_sum_match?(arr)
  puts 'Yes condition matches'
else
  puts 'Invalid Array'
end
# valid arrays are
# [4,6,5,7], [4,5,6,7], etc
```

Tentative Explanation:

[image]

Comment: Wow! Impressed. I had to wrote down some numbers in order to understand it, but definitely works. Do you think there's another way of doing this without turning into a method?

Comment: As you say, `[4,6,5,7]` returns `true`, but it should be `false`, as the elements are non-consecutive. Also, `[3,4,5]` returns `true` even though it does not contain `4` elements.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I think that the array does not need to be sorted. I missed that too.

Comment: Six upvotes so far, most of them coming after the answer was shown to be incorrect! Oh, my! I rarely downvote, but will make an exception because letting an incorrect answer stand is right up there with lust, greed and pride.

Answer (score 3):

If `a` is the array and `n` is the required size:

```
def size_and_consecutive?(a, n)
  a == (a.first..(a.first+n-1)).to_a
end

size_and_consecutive? [3,4,5,6], 4
  #=> true
size_and_consecutive? [4,3,5,6], 4
  #=> false
size_and_consecutive? [3,4,5], 4
  #=> false
```

Answer (score 1):

A compact solution that I could come up with is as follows:

```
def consec(arr)
  is_of_proper_length = (arr.size == 4)
  if(is_of_proper_length)
    are_consec = true
    arr.each_cons(2) {|x,y| are_consec = false unless ((y - x) == 1)}
  end
  is_of_proper_length && are_consec
end
```

Output:

```
consec([1,2,3,4])
 => true 
2.2.0 :051 > consec([0,0,0,0])
 => false 
2.2.0 :052 > consec([4,6,5,7])
 => true 
2.2.0 :053 > consec([4,5,6,7])
 => true 
2.2.0 :054 > consec([5,6,7,8])
 => true 
2.2.0 :055 > consec([2,2,2,5])
 => false 
2.2.0 :056 > consec([2,3,4,5])
 => true 
2.2.0 :057 > consec([1,2,3,4,5])
 => false
```

Comment: The elements of `[4,6,5,7]` are not consecutive, so `false` should be returned.

Comment: to get `sorted_arr.last` you do not need to sort, simply `arr.max` is sufficient