# checking an array for 5 consecutive numbers

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

I was making a poker simulator and tried to define a function which would identify a straight and give it a `handstrength` value of 5.

```
def straightCheck(playerHand):
    playerHand.sort()
    print(playerHand)
    for playerHand in range(len(playerHand)):
        for i in playerHand:
            if playerHand[i] == playerHand [i+1] -1:
                straight = True
            else:
                straight = False
    if straight == True:
        handstrength = 5

x = [1,3,5,4,2]
straightCheck(x)
```

i can't figure out what is wrong with is  but it keeps returning this error message:

```
for i in playerHand:   
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Comment: You are replacing the playerhand argument which probably contains the hand by an integer in the first for loop. Try renaming that iterator

Comment: You are iterating over an integer object which is not iterable.If you want to detect a consecutive sequence with length 5 you better to use `itertools.groupby` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you are trying to iterate of an integer, which cannot (and shouldn't) be done. It seems like your two nested `for` loops should just be one `for`, like `for i in range(len(playerHand) - 1)`, when the `-1` is used so that you don't try to access`playerHand[len(playerHand)]`.

In addition, since you set `straight` to `True` or `False` in every iteration, only your last iteration will count, so you'll get false positives.

Finally, I'm not sure whether you want your function to `return` a value, but currently your function `returns` no data (unless `handstrength` is a global variable). Also, please note that currently, by using `.sort()` you are actually sorting `playerHand`, thus changing it from within the function - this might not be what you want.

A possible function to check whether a hand is straight, similar to your code, is this:

```
def is_straight(playerHand):
    playerHand.sort()
    for i in range(len(playerHand) - 1):
        if playerHand[i] != playerHand [i+1] - 1:
            return False
    return True
```

This function returns `True` if `playerHand` is straight, and `False` otherwise.

Comment: It's probably not good practice to sort an input argument in-place, because that object will end up getting changed outside the function which is likely not what the user expects.  Replacing `playerHand.sort()` with `playerHand = sorted(playerHand)` will make it so the the list is only sorted within the scope of the function.

Comment: You're right, but I was trying to show OP how to convert his code into one that works. I'm not sure whether he wants to change the original list or not, but that's what he originally did.

Comment: Based on the nature of the original mistake, I assume the OP does not know about this type of gotcha at this point. I just wanted to add some extra help since they appear to be a new programmer.

Answer (score 0):

What about this. You sort the list, then convert it to a set and back to a list, which makes it unique. Then the length must be 5 and if so, the difference between max and min for 5 consecutive numbers must be 4. I can't mathematically prove this here, but it should be. ;)

```
>>> x=[2,1,5,3,4]
>>> y=sorted(x)
>>> y=list(set(y))
>>> if len(y) == 5 and y[4]-y[0] == 4: 
...     print "straight"
... 
straight
```

Also see this here: [Check for consecutive numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32973830/check-for-consecutive-numbers?rq=1)

Comment: But 2,3,4,5,6 should be a straight as well, no?

Comment: Oh, probably, you're right. I'm not that pokerface. So, you'd need five consecutives... in that case, y[4]-y[0] should always return 4.